# Jquery suddenly stopped working

Tags: jquery, ajax

I use ajax to submit forms and suddenly they stopped submitting.  I went to the debugger in chrome and I got this:

Uncaught TypeError: $(...).ajaxForm is not a function

(anonymous function)    @   index.php:3775

fire    @   jquery.js:1075

self.fireWith   @   jquery.js:1193

jQuery.extend.ready @   jquery.js:435

DOMContentLoaded    @   jquery.js:949

The way I've been including jquery is:

```
<base href="http://website.com/">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.js"></script> 
<script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/universal.css">
<link href="/css/zozo.tabs.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="/js/zozo.tabs.min.js"></script>
```

So far I've tried switching the order of them, adding them beneath the html and body close, and linking new copies, specifically:

Nothing has worked so far.

Comment: Are you getting any `404`s?

Comment: Is there a new import that you included after which it stopped working?

Comment: not that i can recall. It was working yesterday, and then today it was not.

Comment: Seems like loading issue. Include `ajaxform` function inside timeout and delay it for a while. Check if that works out. `jquery.form.js` was also there from before?

Comment: pratikwebdev I am not sure how to do that, can you explain and submit as answer?

Comment: Probably because github is not a CDN. Can get that script from various CDN's or download it and serve from own server